# Why isn't index used for this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 300K rows and b-tree index on "operator" field.
While I'm runnig this query it isn't using an index.
"operator" has the same data-type as dict.vw_dict_operator.id.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  
    id,
    name
FROM
    dict.vw_dict_operator self 
WHERE

            EXISTS (
                SELECT 42 FROM ti.ti_flight_availability flight_avail
                WHERE flight_avail.operator = self.id
            )   
ORDER BY
    self.name 

"Sort  (cost=3349.66..3351.02 rows=545 width=18)"
"  Sort Key: dict_operator.name"
"  ->  Seq Scan on dict_operator  (cost=0.00..3324.89 rows=545 width=18)"
"        Filter: ((NOT trash) AND (subplan))"
"        SubPlan"
"          ->  Seq Scan on ti_flight_availability flight_avail  (cost=0.00..8513.66 rows=3750 width=0)"
"                Filter: (operator = $0)"
```

UPD: thanks @gbn.  index isnot used when joining tables as well

```
EXPLAIN SELECT self.id, self.name 
FROM dict.vw_dict_operator self JOIN ti.ti_flight_availability flight_avail
ON flight_avail.operator = self.id

"Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..92988.47 rows=228639 width=18)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on ti_flight_availability flight_avail  (cost=0.00..7754.33 rows=303733 width=4)"
"  ->  Index Scan using pk_dict_operator on dict_operator  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=18)"
"        Index Cond: (dict_operator.id = flight_avail.operator)"
"        Filter: (NOT dict_operator.trash)"
```

Comment: I don't know about using the index, but dependent subqueries are usually bad mojo.

Comment: @R. Bemrose Could you write realization for this task without subqueries, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a JOIN? And did you ANALYZE? What about the statistics? Check pg_stats for this table to get some more information. reltuples and relpages in pg_class are also interesting for the table and it's indexes.

---

Edit:
The JOIN expects 228639 rows. The sequential scan expects 303733 rows, only a fraction extra. When these 100k records are all over the place, the database has to scan the relpages anyway. A sequential scan will be faster than an index scan, a sequential scan a (fast) sequentail read, an index scan will be two (!) slow random reads: the information from the index **and** the data from the table.

If you think the plan is wrong, ANALYZE the table and show us information from pg_stats and pg_class about the tables and indexes.

```
ANALYZE;

SELECT relpage, reltuples WHERE relname = 'table_or_index_name';

SELECT * FROM pg_stats WHERE tablename = 'name of your table';
```

Comment: sorry, JOIN doesn't use index too. its takes a long time to perform ANALYZE. 
reltuples: 303733
relpages: 4717

unfortunately I don't have an idea what useful information I can grab from pg_class, pg_stats

Comment: See my edit, and you have to ANALYZE. You could do it on just these tables, but you have to do it. What version of PostgreSQL do you have?

Comment: version 8.3
reltuples: 303733 relpages: 4717
http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/1516/screenshotrz.png

Comment: An index on operator is not going to help very much, only 80 distinct values on 303733 records. These 80 values will be all over the place, the database has to read the entire table, a seq scan. Your original query, using EXISTS, is a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Would it use the index if you did a join instead?

Answer (score 0):

What index you have have on dict.vw_dict_operator?

EXISTS is a form of JOIN (simplistic, I know) and it's possible the index is ignored because there is no convenient one to JOIN to. So it scans instead.

Edit:

the JOIN plan is not using an index on ti_flight_availability either... but you state you have an index on it?

Comment: CREATE TABLE dict.dict_operator
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_dict_operator PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Comment: @noxvile: and on ti_flight_availability?

Comment: CREATE INDEX ix_ti_flight_availability_operator
  ON ti.ti_flight_availability
  USING btree
  (operator);